# Devstack installation failing in uploading Fedora image

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am installing Devstack stable/Juno on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I followed this steps: cloning devstack, modify `stackrc` "Git base to https", and I didn't modify `localrc` file, I'm giving the passwords when I run ./stack.sh

But i'm having these errors, Could you help me?

```
+ image_name=Fedora-x86_64-20-20140618-sda
+ disk_format=qcow2
+ container_format=bare
+ is_arch ppc64
++ uname -m
+ [[ i686 == \p\p\c\6\4 ]]
+ '[' bare = bare ']'
+ '[' '' = zcat ']'
+ openstack --os-token 2c0781724c1b4ed1990b62ac4996b83b --os-url http://192.168.1.8:9292 image create Fedora-x86_64-20-20140618-sda --public --container-format=bare --disk-format qcow2
ERROR: openstack <html>
 <head>
  <title>401 Unauthorized</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>401 Unauthorized</h1>
  This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser does not understand how to supply the credentials required.<br /><br />
 </body>
</html> (HTTP 401)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just clean my browser cookies and run ./stack.sh again and it worked